# checking if list contains the object - java

Tags: java

I am writing the image processing program, and I have a problem with a list.

I have a list with Points.

```
     class Point1{
        private int x;
        private int y;

        Point1(int x,int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

       int getX(){ return this.x; }
       int getY() {return this.y; }
    }

    ArrayList<Point1> list = new ArrayList();
```

And now, I create new Point, for example new Point(4,3); 
I want to check if there is a point in my list which has the same coordinates. The problem is that

```
    list.contains(Object a)
```

is checking if if on my list there is a particular object. It will work if I put

```
    Point1 first = new Point(1,1);  
    list.add(first);
    list.contains(first) // and this is true
```

but:

```
    Point second = new Point(2,2);
    list.add(second);
    list.contains(new Point(2,2)); <- false
```

how can I check it?

Comment: Have you overwritten the `hashCode` and `equals` methods of your class?

Comment: Yes. Yes you should. Here's a good reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Comment: It's what is used by `contains` to see if it's contained in the list, so yes, you should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List determine whether two objects are equal by using `equals` method.

If your class won't override `public boolean equals(Object o){..}` method, it will will inherit it from closest supertype which provides that implementation.

If your class doesn't extend any other class, it will means it implicitly extends `Object` class. So it will inherit `equals` implementation from it. Problem is that this implementation looks like:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

so it uses reference equality operator `==`. This means that `equals` will only return true if object will be compared with *itself* (references to other objects will always be different than reference to `this` object).

In your case your equals method to return `true` also for *other* instances of `Point1` if their *state* (value of `x` and `y`) is equal.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if(this == other)
        return true;
    if(!other instanceof Point1)
        return false;
    Point1 otherPoint= (Point1)other;
    if(this.x == otherPoint.getX() && this.y == otherPoint.getY())
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

And you can get the result you want:
[image]

**BTW while overriding `equals` method we should also override `hashcode` method. See [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2265503)**

Answer (score 3):

You need to override `equals` on your `Point` class.  Your `Point` class must be responsible for determining whether another `Point` object is "equal" to the current object.  An `ArrayList` will call `equals` to determine if the object passed in to `contains` is "equal" to any item in the list.

If you don't override `equals`, then `Point` will inherit [`equals` from `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), which will simply see if it's the same exact object.  That's why your first code "works", because you are re-using `first`.  It also explains why your second code doesn't "work", because you used a different object.

Also, if you override `equals`, it's best to override `hashCode` also (and vice versa).

Comment: "it's best to override" - more precociously, two objects that are equals must return the same hash code. Thus, usually when overriding `equals`, `hashCode` must be overridden.

Comment: Eclipse will generate hashcode and equals implementations that are pretty decent. If that is not an option, apache commons-lang (3.x) has utilities for building hash codes and equals methods.